# Show and hide parent and children divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contains children html elements, when I click on div children elements will display, in that hide button also there when I click on hide parent will hide.
`please help me`

Comment: Add your code also that you had tried??

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none` in css on the div you want to hide.
If you want to show them, use `$("#yourdiv").css("display","block");` in your jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can post your relevant code, anyway here example made for you :

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">Hey All
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c
    <button class="hide" data-type="parent">Hide Parent</button>
    <button class="hide" data-type="children">Hide Children</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">Hey All 1
 <div>a</div>
 <div>b</div>
 <div>c
    <button class="hide" data-type="parent">Hide Parent</button>
    <button class="hide" data-type="children">Hide Children</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.parent').click(function () {
  // show direct child when parent div was clicked
  $(this).children().css('display', 'block');
});

// hide parent or child
$('.hide').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var type = $(this).data('type');
  var parent = $(this).closest('.parent');

  if (type === "parent") parent.css('display', 'none');
  else parent.children().css('display', 'none');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/m58Lu60m/)